# How to read, manipulate and rewrite text in file using python

Tags: python, file, io

How can I read data from a file, manipulate the data and rewrite it back to the file without wasting memory on a temp file if the file is too big to be processed in one chunk?

Comment: By manipulating you mean to change characters in it or by adding/removing several characters in it thus changing the output file size? In the first case just read in chunks then overwrite the chunks in the file. In the second case (modifying the lenth of the file) it won't work, you have to create a separate output file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code should work:

```
chunksize = 64*1024 #arbitrary number
offset = 0
with open(path, 'r+b') as file:
    while True:
        file.seek(chunksize*offset)  # sets pointer to reading spot
        chunk = file.read(chunksize)
        if len(chunk) == 0:  # checks if EoF
            break
        elif len(chunk) % 16 != 0:  # adds bytes to the chunk if it is the last chunk and size doesnt divide by 16 (if processing text of specific size, my case 16 bytes)
            chunk += ' ' * (16 - len(chunk) % 16)
        file.seek(chunksize*offset)  # returns pointer to beginning of the chunk in order to rewrite the data that was encrypted
        file.write(do_something(chunk))  # edits and writes data to file
        offset += 1
```

The code reads the data, returns to the beginning of the chunk and overwrites it. it will not work if the manipulated data is larger than the read data.

Comment: This will leave parts of the file unchanged if the manipulated data is smaller than `chunksize`. Instead of seeking to `chunksize*offset` you should keep track of where the modified data actually ends.

Comment: In order for it to work you have to have manipulated data exactly the size of read data. if you don't use `chunksize * offset` you will have corrupt data between the end of the written data and the beginning of the read data